# Alert in React Native goes away as the state changes

Tags: react-native, react-redux, state, alert

I am calling forgotPassword api in the app and once its response comes from and state changes in reducer i get callback as i have useEffect in my component. I want to show user an alert that his password is reset successfully, but it shows only for 1 sec and goes away, i think whole view renders again. How can i make alert to staty until use taps on the button in alert.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (forgotPasswordData != null) {
  Alert.alert('Success',forgotPasswordData.message, [{
    text: 'OKAY',
    onPress: () => {
      dispatch({
        type: authActions.RESET_FORGOT_PASSWORD_DATA,
      });
      console.log("Hello")
      setEmail('');
      setselectedAssociation(null);
      setAssociationName('');
    }  
   }]
);
```

}
}, [forgotPasswordData]);

Comment: if you add a `console.log(forgotPasswordData);` inside the `useEffect`, does the value change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `forgotPasswordData` reset, `useEffect` will rerender again so the best option to alert the user is where you're getting a response.

You can create a callback function and define `Alert` in it and pass this callback to action and in `Saga` where you get a result, you can trigger this callback so It will `Alert` on view.

Comment: The response of API comes from the reducer. I am not calling API in the same component. API is called with an action and response is passed on to reducer and then I get useEffect called when state changes with response from api.

Comment: @AKumar ok got it. I have updated my answer please check and can achieve that way